# Countdown days from today date to a specific date each year, using jquery or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will countdown the days from today's date to a specific given date, using javascript or jquery.

This is what I have now and it works pretty fine, but how can I make it so it will run every year?

```js
function daysDifference($startDate, $endDate) {
    oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    return Math.ceil(($endDate.getTime() - $startDate.getTime()) / oneDay);  
}

$today = new Date();
$endDate = new Date(2019, 12, 31);

document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  + daysDifference($today, $endDate) + ' days left for the new Year';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: you want the end date to be updated every year ?

Comment: yes exactly @Gui3!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, you just need to change your dates to:

```
$today = new Date();
$endDate = new Date($today.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
```

Edit:
After the current day is past, but still on the year, you can do this to keep the count going:

```
if($today > $endDate) {
    $endDate =  new Date($today.getFullYear() + 1, 11, 31);
}
```

This should keep it going forever.

Comment: @Designer make sure you check the edited answer, as I only tried to reach the date once the year starts. So there's a portion of the year that will not be taken in consideration, please add the edited portion of the code to ensure your code works fine :)

Comment: Also, if it does, please consider marking the answer as the solution so it helps other people too :)

Comment: there must be a mistake in the code i guess! The result is 71 days left instead of 41 days !!!

Comment: Updated: I just realized that months start from zero in javascript! (Jan=0, Feb=1 etc) so your code works fine. Thank you !

Comment: Oh, yes. I see you changed the month's value in the edits. I just noticed. I'm glad it helped.